# Java program gives incorrect Taylor series term for function e^x

Tags: java, algorithm, taylor-series

```
//java program that asks the user  to input a number that e^x=1+x+x^2/2! +x^3/3!... e is a mathematical constant equal to 2.718...

import java.util.Scanner;
public class taylor_2 {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    double x; //input for x
    double factorial=1; //initializes factorial
    int counter=1; //initializes counter
    double result=1; //initializes result

    System.out.println("Enter non negative number"); //asks user to enter x
    x=input.nextInt();

 //output in while loop will continue to be generated if user doesn't entered a negative number

    while(x<1){
      System.out.println("I said entered a positive number");
      x=input.nextInt();
    }
    while(x>counter){
      factorial=factorial*counter;//factorial formula
      result=result+(Math.pow(x,counter))/factorial; //equation for e^x=1+x+x^2/2! +x^3/3!
      counter++;
    }
    System.out.println("Taylor series is " +result);//output for taylor equation e^x
  }
}
```

Here is the output of my code:

> Enter non negative number
>
> 2
>
> Taylor series is 4.0

When I entered 2 , it should have outputted 7.3890560983 instead of 4.0 since e=2.718... and e^2=7.3890560983. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Side note on your many // comments: they are pretty much worthless. Comments should **only** be written when you want to explain **why** something is done; but your comments just repeat what is already there and obvious. Such comments just make reading source code **harder**. They obfuscate instead of clarify. Besides: class names should start with upper case letters; not lowercase.

Comment: And to help with your question: why do you initialize `result` to 1?
And why didn't you add some more system.out.println statements to print out the various values in your loop? In other words: you expect others to debug your code; whereas ... you already have the code; you have it running; and you could easily find out what "happens" during computation.

Comment: The taylor series is summing for values of `counter` from 0 to infinity, you are summing only up to `x`, which is not nearly enough to get a close value to the convergence of the series. Increase it significnatly. Change the line `while(x>counter){ ` to something like `while(100>counter){ `

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the Taylor series is not the same function that e^x.
It will return a function that is close to the function e^x.

For understanding it better, I recommend you to look the second picture of the next link:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series

You can see in the previous picture that as n is getting larger the function is getting more accurate.

Your code's problem is that your `x` value is your `n` value, and this is not really true.

x: Must be the value you want to now e^x.

n: Is the accurate of your equation. Larger means more accurate.

So you must change `while(x>counter)` with `while(n>counter)`, where n can be either a variable with the user selected accuracy, or a constant with your selected accurcy.

I think that until `x=100`, `n=150` should work.

I hope that helps you! :)

Comment: Don't forget to [credit me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30166785/java-program-gives-incorrect-taylor-series-term-for-function-ex#comment48441564_30166785)

Comment: How can I credit you, I'am new in that website and I am a bit lose. Thank for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an answer here: [EXP to Taylor series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362573/exp-to-taylor-series?rq=1) for c++, even though the algorithm is slightly different to yours. Here's its Java version:

```
public class TaylorSeries {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter x:");
    double x = input.nextDouble();

    double result = calcExp(x);
    System.out.println("calcExp(x) = " + result);
    System.out.println("       e^x = " + Math.pow(Math.E, x));
}

static double calcExp(double x) {
    double eps = 0.0000000000000000001;
    double elem = 1.0;
    double sum = 0.0;
    boolean negative = false;
    int i = 1;
    sum = 0.0;

    if (x < 0) {
        negative = true;
        x = -x;
    }

    do {
        sum += elem;
        elem *= x / i;
        i++;
        if (sum > Double.MAX_VALUE) {
            System.out.println("Too Large");
            break;
        }
    }
    while (elem >= eps);

    return negative ? 1.0 / sum : sum;
}
}
```

The output:

```
Enter x:
2
calcExp(x) = 7.389056098930649
       e^x = 7.3890560989306495
```

All credit should go to the answer here: [EXP to Taylor series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362573/exp-to-taylor-series?rq=1). I have only converted c++ code to Java